# LinqToExcel:How to get specific row in Excel

Tags: excel, linq

I have an excel that looks like

```
ID   Name   DepartmentID Ext
1298 Alice  AA1152       1221
1299 Andrew AA1152       1235
2894 Jack   AA1152       1285
2723 Daniel AA1152       4239
```

All employees are in the same department, and I want to get the DepartmentID from excel to link to the department name in database.

I've read this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/659643/Csharp-Query-Excel-and-CSV-Files-Using-LinqToExcel but it has to read the entire file and access sequentially in foreach loop.

How can I get only one row from excel using LinqToExcel library?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `First()` to return only the first result :

```
var artistAlbums = from a in excelFile.Worksheet(sheetName) select a;
var firstAlbum = artistAlbums.First();
```

And to get one specific row, combine `Skip()` and `First()`, for example :

```
var fifthAlbum = artistAlbums.Skip(4).First();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . I ended up using artistAlums.First() to accomplish my needed, it automatically skip the header. But when I tried to use Skip().First(), it pops up an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
var excelData = new ExcelQueryFactory(excelFileName);
var yourRow = from c in excelData.Worksheet<YourMappedClass>(WorksheetName) where c.Id==SomeValue select c;
```

There are quite a few other things you can accomplish as well as explained in their [github](https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel) page.